# Proving that $f'$ is not continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives, proof-explanation

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^\frac{2}{3} \sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x>0\\ 
0 & x \le0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I have calculated $f'$ here:

$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{3}{2}x^\frac{1}{2} \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{\sqrt x} \cos \frac{1}{x} & x>0\\ 
0 & x \le0 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

So, I want to prove that $f'$ is not continuous (at least this is what I think).

Now I have 2 options: proving that $\lim_{x \to x_{0}}f'(x) \ne f'(x_{0})$ or checking if $f'$ is differentiable, meaning trying to prove that $f''$ does not exists.

I have tried both options with no luck...

Any hints will be appreciated! :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first term in $f'(x)$ goes to $0$ and the second term has no limit.

Comment: Great! I will try that now.

Comment: "Checking if $f'$ is differentiable" will not help (except that a positive result would show that $f'$ is continuous, but not the other way round)

Comment: compute $f'(\frac1{2\pi n})$, $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{1}{2 \pi n}$? Why should I choose this $x$?

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy said, $\lim_{x \to 0^-}[ \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \cos \frac{1}{x}]$ doesn't exists, because $\lim_{x \to 0^-}[ \frac{1}{\sqrt x}]$ does not exists, and $\lim_{x \to 0^-}[\cos \frac{1}{x}]$ does not exists. Is that correct?

Comment: There is a typo in your expression for $f(x) $. It should be $x^{3/2}\sin(1/x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the function $f'$ is continuous, then for any sequence $x_n \rightarrow 0$ such that $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, the following must be true: $f'(x_n) = \frac{3}{2} x_{n}^{\frac{1}{2}} \sin (\frac{1}{x_n}) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}} \cos(\frac{1}{x_n}) \rightarrow 0$.

To prove that $f'$ is discontinuous at $0$, you need to find a sequence $x_n$ as mentioned above, but with $f'(x_n)$ being divergent.

Such a counter-example could be $x_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n}$.

It is clear that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and that $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n$. However,

$f'(x_n) = \frac{3}{2} (\frac{1}{2\pi n})^{\frac{1}{2}} \sin (2\pi n) - \sqrt{2\pi n} \cos(2\pi n) = -\sqrt{2\pi n} \rightarrow - \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

In other words, $f'(x_n)$ is divergent, and thus, $f'(x)$ has a discontinuity at 0.